# Unable to extract data from model's(database)

Tags: python, django

I am building an legal compliance webapp that includes the relationships between entries, etc. I have separate models that are Company_Masters, Location_Masters, dept, employ and Comp_Info. On my index page I would like to list all the compliances and would like to create, update and edit them. But I don’t know how to use all the models

```
#view.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Company_Masters, Location_Masters,dept, emplo, Comp_Info 

def home(request):
    mylist = zip(Company_Masters.objects.all(), Location_Masters.objects.all() , dept.objects.all(), emplo.objects.all())
    context = {
        'mylist': mylist
    }
    return render(request,'compliance/home.html',context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Company_Masters
    model = Location_Masters
    model = dept 
    model = emplo
    model = Comp_Info
    template_name = 'compliance/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'mylist'

def about(request):
    return render(request,'compliance/about.html')  


URLS.PY

#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='compliance-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='compliance-about')

]

HOME.HTML

{% extends "compliance/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for comp,loc,dept,emp in mylist %}


      <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">COMPLIANCE 1</a>
              <small class="text-muted">DATE EXPIRY</small>
            </div>


            <p class="article-content"> COMPANY ID: {{ comp.comp_id }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">COMPANY NAME: {{ comp.comp_name }}</p>

            <p class="article-content">LOCATION ID: {{ loc.loc_id}}</p>
            <p class="article-content">LOCATION NAME: {{ loc.loc_name}}</p>

            <p class="article-content">DEPT ID: {{ dept.dept_id}}</p>
            <p class="article-content">DEPT NAME: {{ dept.dept_name}}</p>

            <p class="article-content">EMPLOYEE ID: {{ emp.emp_id}}</p>
            <p class="article-content">EMPLOYEE NAME: {{ emp.emp_name}}</p>

            <!-- <p class="article-content">EMPLOYEE EMAIL: {{ emp.emp_email}}</p> -->

            </div>

      </article>

{% endfor %}      
{% endblock content %}`enter code here`
```

So basically I am unable to extract data from these models(database)

Comment: The `ListView` will only show one model at a time - in the case of the ListView above, the last model defined will be the only model retrieved. In order to show the contents of your different models, you will have to create a generic `View`, retrieve the data from the models using the standard `model.objects.filter` mechanism and then pass that to the template for display and editing. In Short, You cannot define multiple `models` in a `ListView`

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, do not use `zip` and define each in your context:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'mylist': {
            'comp': Company_Masters.objects.all(),
            'loc': Location_Masters.objects.all(),
            'dept': dept.objects.all(),
            'emp': emplo.objects.all()
        }
    }
    return render(request,'compliance/home.html',context)
```

will return a dictionary `mylist` into your template from which you can access each of the other dictionaries using dot notation `mylist.comp` as an example. this is not the ideal solution but short of really know what you are trying to accomplish we can try to get you there.

In your template, you would change to:

```
{% extends "compliance/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

      <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">COMPLIANCE 1</a>
              <small class="text-muted">DATE EXPIRY</small>
            </div>

            {% for comp in mylist.comp %}
            <p class="article-content"> COMPANY ID: {{ comp.comp_id }}</p>
            <p class="article-content">COMPANY NAME: {{ comp.comp_name }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for loc in mylist.loc %}
            <p class="article-content">LOCATION ID: {{ loc.loc_id}}</p>
            <p class="article-content">LOCATION NAME: {{ loc.loc_name}}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for dept in mylist.dept %}
            <p class="article-content">DEPT ID: {{ dept.dept_id}}</p>
            <p class="article-content">DEPT NAME: {{ dept.dept_name}}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for emp in mylist.emp %}
            <p class="article-content">EMPLOYEE ID: {{ emp.emp_id}}</p>
            <p class="article-content">EMPLOYEE NAME: {{ emp.emp_name}}</p>
            <!-- <p class="article-content">EMPLOYEE EMAIL: {{ emp.emp_email}}</p> -->
            {% endfor %}

            </div>

      </article>

{% endblock content %}
```

**But, I would hazard a guess and say that this is unlikely to get you the end result you wanted - although you did not explicitly say it, I am guessing, your goal was really to join those tables into a single result. That is a larger answer and would require knowledge of your models**

Meaning, if your goal was to access all `emplo` records, you would use the `ForeignKey` to `dept`, `Location_Masters` and `Company_Masters` to get the properly associated records. something along the lines of `emplo.objects.select_related('dept', 'Location_Masters', 'Company_Masters').all()` but that would mean that all the foreignkeys are in emplo (again guessing at your models)

*Note: you should consider reading about proper naming in python/django - your model classes should all be Capitalized and not use underscores in the names - also it is good practice to be explicitly name your class and variable names so that the next person who reads your code will understand what you were trying to accomplish*